# build JSON from REST API call

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api

I am retrieving list item values in sharepoint using REST API.

Now I want to store these values in JSON so I can just call the JSON and retrieve the values in another function

```
$.ajax({
    url: lib,
    method: 'GET',
    async: false,
    headers: {"accept":"application/json;odata=verbose"},
    success: function(data) {
        /* console.log(data); */
        if(data.d != undefined) {
            var temp_prod= [];
            $.each(data.d.results, function (i,item) {

            }//each
        } });
```

I want to construct the JSON to be like this

```
var products = [{ Dell Laptop: { price: 1000.00, color: black },
                  HP Laptop: { price: 900.00, color: grey }]
```

and can I access these using

```
var dellLaptopPrice = products["Dell Laptop"].price;
var dellLaptopColor = products["Dell Laptop"].color;
```

Answer (score 0):

got it using this code

```
var products = {}

$.each(data.d.results, function (i,item) {
      products[item.Name] = {name: item.Name, price: item.Price, color: item.Color }

}
```